# SQL Server: Insert Into new table with old table data and different column types

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am in the process of a data migration for the current application we are working on. The migration involves an old database and a new database. The old database was not normalized and had huge tables. We have created a new database that now has many tables to better store the data. My question now is:
I have an old table. I am trying to copy the data from the old table, insert into the new table. The new table is now converting one field from varchar to int and is a FK to a separate table (so 3 tables involved) I have given a snippet of the table structures below and what needs to be accomplished. I have searched all over for the past 2 days and just cant seem to find the answer.

OldTable (PersonID, FileName, AttachType)

NewTable (PersonID, FileName, AttachTypeID)

tblAttachType (AttachTypeID, TypeName)

So I need the old table data transferred to the new table and the AttachType needs to look at "TypeName" to match, then in the new table, insert the "AttachTypeID" from "tblAttachType".

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to insert the data that you need by selecting from the tables you have.

```
INSERT INTO NewTable (PersonID, FileName, AttachTypeID)
SELECT o.PersonID, o.FileName, t.AttachTypeID
FROM OldTable o
JOIN tblAttachType t on o.AttachType = t.TypeName
```